# Sharing sockets (WINSOCK) by sending them to each other between 2 servers

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I am trying to write a distributed server system (consisting of server 1="main", and server 2="replacement" for now). Don't mind some **dirty** methods, it's just to achieve a basic function a distributed server would achive.

Currently I have **both servers** running via `SO_REUSEADDR` and a TCP Socket (maybe UDP will solve my problem, but I wanna try it either way with TCP first) on the **same machine**.

Main server sends establishes a connection with the Replacement server and clients connecting to it.
Now what I want to achieve: The main server should send the socket of the connecting clients to the replacement server, so in case the main server can't work anymore (timeout or what ever) the replacement server can work with the clients and send/recv with them.
The socket I send from main to the replacement server is the one I get with `ClientSocket = ::accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);` where ClientSocket is a `SOCKET` (UINT_PTR).

The replacement server can't send/recv to the clients even though the main server gets terminated midway.
Is that because each server, even though they run on the same port, need to be connected via a `::connect` from the clients?

EDIT: If my theory is true, this should be solved by using UDP instead of TCP as well, no?

EDIT2: With distributed server I mean a server which in case of a failure will be replaced by another without the clients task getting interrupted.

EDIT3: If there is a better and more simple way to do this, I'd like to know about that as well. I'm not too fond of sockets and server communication as of now that's how I came up with my idea to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a socket between machines. A socket is an OS concept. It represents (in this case) a connection between the server and a client. This connection cannot be resumed on a different machine that has a different IP address because a TCP connection is defined to be established between a pair of addresses and a pair of ports.

The `UINT_PTR` on one machine means nothing to another machine. It is an opaque value. It is an OS handle.

UDP does not solve the problem since the client needs to notice that the IP address is is communicating with has changed.

Even if you manage that you have the problem that a server failure kills all data on that server. The other server cannot resume with the exact same data. This is a basic problem of distributed computing. You cannot keep the state of all three machines completely in sync.

Make the clients tolerate interruptions by retrying. Make the servers stateless and put all data into a database.

This is a very hard problem to solve. Seek off-the-shelve solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to write that both servers are running in my case on the same machine and because of that I described my solution as a "dirty method".
I try to synchronize the data (and as such the states of my main server) by sending all messages the main server receives from the clients to the replacement server as well. The replacement server will "simulate" the same stuff the main server will do, without sending messages to the client.

Comment: That makes more sense. You can duplicate a socket handle on Windows but any data read will only go to one process. That doesn't work. I doubt Windows or Linux have a forking socket API. You need to manage that yourself. So what exactly is the problem you are facing? Just duplicate the data and channel it to both.

Comment: Well the problem is as described, simply by sending the SOCKET data to the replacement server doesn't seem to work. The clients seem to know when the main server stops or dies and abort. The replacement server seems to have problems when I try to recv/send from the SOCKET I got from the main server. I get several Winsock errors. Since it's just 3 digits in my case and I checked if they were the same on both "servers" this shouldnt be the case. Though after reading your answer, I'm planning to go with a different approach.

Comment: This approach cannot work because the primary might die right after reading data. That causes the data to be lost. You need to fork the data to both processes. Passing a handle value from one process to the next does not work. You need to duplicate the socket into the secondary process. But again that approach cannot work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got a nice idea from your post. I'll try to handle my current server application(s) with an intermediate server (or again 2 of them in terms of distributed systems). Though my current server is dependent from the sockets of the clients, I would just have to make him independent. In terms of the task the server has to fullfill I think I would be better of with an approach like this.

Comment: That's kind of what I was about to recommend. Put a small server in front of the two backends. Make it relay/duplicate the data stream. Make it detect failure in one of the backends. Since that server has little code it is not prone to fail.

Comment: On Windows you can indeed do exactly this. Why, is another question.

Comment: @EJP you can duplicate the socket but not fork the incoming data stream. At least not as a native feature.

Comment: I am also trying to load a socket in another server running on same machine. I have a login server that allows a user to log in, much ,ike a telnet BBS. I then write the socket number to a file and then the second server reads the file and tries to connect to the socket. For some reason my second server is not able to connect to the socket. However, I have seen BBS software do this - write a socket to a file, and a door program reads the socket and connects. I'm not sure what I have to do to the socket before passing it over to the second server.

Comment: @James you need to call DuplicateHandle to create a handle copy in the target process. Then, send *that* number.

Comment: @usr I don't think the BBS software I mentioned before does that. They are able to save a socket descriptor to a file and then the door programs read in that descriptor. DuplicateHandle() is for windows processes.

Comment: @James maybe they start the door program suspended, then duplicate the handle into the running process, write the handle value and resume the program. Possible, but a very elaborate dance and a bad idea.

Comment: @usr  I did some research on the DuplicateHandle() function and found a similar function WSADuplicateSocket(). When launching the door program I can see they probably do get the process ID and then duplicate the socket. But now I am trying to come up with a way to get the process ID of my other server already running. I'm thinking that server can call GetCurrentProcessId() and save the ID to a file, then the first server can get the process ID from there. I agree, seems like a lot of work to do something that should be simple.